# Javascript: Iterating over array of objects and forming new array

Tags: javascript, json, loops

I want to convert the following array as follows:

```
[{'dog' : 2} {'cat' : 4} , {'chimp' : 3}] -> [{'text' : 'dog', 'size' : 2}, {'text' : 'cat', 'size' : 4}, {'text' : 'chimp', 'size' : 3}]
```

In pseudocode

```
for obj in array:
    new_obj = {'text' : obj.key, 'size' : obj.val}
    new_array.append(new_obj)
return new_array
```

Comment: [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let arr = [{
  'dog': 2
}, {
  'cat': 4
}, {
  'chimp': 3
}];

let result = arr.map(a => {
  let key = Object.keys(a)[0];
  return {
    text: key,
    size: a[key]
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: why are you using `let` ?

Comment: @webdeb—why did you use *const*? ;-)

Comment: @RobG because I do not plan to re-assign the variable

Comment: @webdeb—I guess the point is that the OP doesn't infer any criteria to determine whether any one of *var*, *let* or *const* is more suitable than the other. So questioning the use of one or the other is moot. I use *var* except where *const* or *let* are explicitly required, but that's just me. ;-)

Comment: I Totally agree, just `let` me clever shit, it's not `const`antly :D

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not that hard, you can just use

`Array.map` and `Object.keys()`

```
const newArray = oldArray.map(item => {
  const key = Object.keys(item)[0];
  // Add some guard to handle empty objects..

  return { text: key, size: item[key] };
});
```